# Non-sudo wifi deactivation

Tags: shortcut-keys, sudo

I have ASUS N76VB laptop. I am affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173681) in asus_nb_wmi driver, so I can't use Fn-F2 key combination to toggle wifi.

The guy from the thread about bug workaround uses `rfkill` command to block and unblock wifi in his toggling script. `rfkill`, however, needs root-access to execute these commands, so if I want to assign a hotkey to this script, I'll have to add rfkill to sudoers list, which I want to *leave* as an ugly, emergency-way idea.

So I want to know if I can disable my wifi module without gaining root-access. Pretty `dbus-send` commands appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use NetworkManager, you can try this command to toggle wifi off and on:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
nmcli radio wifi on
```

This commands works over D-Bus and is about the equivalent to `rfkill block wifi; rfkill unblock wifi`.

Comment: Yes, I use it. But your commands cause an error "Unknown object "wifi". Try to execute "nmcli help""

Comment: @mekkanizer It must be a feature of newer NM versions then. Try `nmcli nm wifi off` (and `nmcli nm wifi on`) instead.

Comment: I dunno if you should edit your answer to include this earlier versions workaround, but thanks anyways